# ASP.NET MVC Application won't update some controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, publishing

I'm publishing to IIS using the publish web option within visual studio 2012 for web applications. When I publish the console tells me building and publishing was successful, and for the most part everything does publish correctly. But there is one controller that hasn't been publishing recently. There are no errors, but it just won't publish.

I tried deleting the controller and view, cleaning the solution, shutting down my webserver, deleting the entire publish directory, and republishing. But when I start up the server again the old controller is still there! So I created a new controller with a different name and published - the new controller successfully published along with the old phantom one, but now that I need to make changes I've run into the same problem with the new controller... I don't understand why this is happening. Anyone seen this before?

Comment: check in solution explorer. right click the controller and check its properties. Specifically its copy to output directory status

Comment: @DaveA "Do not copy". This is for a third version that I just re-created. The previous 2 are completely deleted but are still being published.

Comment: try changing status to always copy

Comment: @DaveA I renamed the 3rd version of the controller to it's original name, and switched copy to output directory to copy always, and now it seems to execute the new code (this resolved my core issue). The 3rd version of the controller is no longer addressable since it was renamed, but the second version is. Why does this happen??

Comment: Note: the second version of the controller I'm referring to does not exist in the solution - I deleted it and replaced it with the third version.

Comment: sorry bizorke, i didn't understand your first of last 2 posts. sounds like part of your problem was resolved but not all?

Comment: @DaveA No it's resolved I'm just wondering why I'm still able to access a controller which was deleted.

Comment: Somethings kooky here. are you using TFS of other version control?

Comment: @DaveA No version control. I'm the only developer working on this project and have soul access to this server.

Comment: @DaveA I'm not overly concerned with figuring out why the deleted file continues to be magically published. Please feel free to post your "copy to output" answer below, and I will close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. open *solution explorer*
2. right click on the file
3. click **properties**
4. change **Copy To Output** to **Copy Always** or **Copy if newer**