# asp.net user control changes not getting picked up

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, user-controls, kentico

I have made some changes inside the user control, to both the code behind and aspx. When i run my local development or the dev site (posted the changes to dev site). I don't see my changes. I recycled the app pools and restarted the dev site as well.

I have placed break points in the code. The code never hits those. When i mouse over the break points after the page has executed, i get unreachable code message (yellow popop and attached).

I am only able to see my changes (local dev and dev site) after deleting asp.net temp internet files on my local machine and dev box.

I have just posted the code to the staging site and it is doing the same thing. Here i can't delete the asp.net temp files during the middle of the day or restart iis.

The project is

VS 2012
ASP.NET 4.5
IIS 7
Kentico CMS - Classic Asp.Net

This is the first time i am seeing this behavior. Has some one else seen this and how did you fix it?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a different browser? Or cleared your browser's cache?  It sounds like a caching issue.

Comment: I forgot to add the break point attachment, it is now attached.

Comment: I have restarted my machine now, made one more change and it is again not being picked up. I deleted the asp.net temp files again for my change to be picked up.

Comment: Sort of silly but try a rebuild all on the solution/project and do clean on the solution/project as well.  Also open the aspx page and refresh the design view.

Comment: I have tried all of these.

Comment: I got the same issue on staging (2 servers) and production (2 servers) as well. I have a custom classic asp.net site, setup as an application under our intranet site (MVC) on the same servers and that is working normal.

Comment: You said it kentico is a web applicaion under a custom MVC Project, so here is my silly Question, are the dll's from kentico web application, uptodate? and/or are the file being copied to the right folder?  something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766208/asp-net-mvc-application-wont-update-some-controllers)

Comment: Yes. No such problem was there when i worked on it last time. I have checked old cases as well and there is nothing that is popping out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kentico had a caching bug that got fixed in HotFix upgrade 7.0.86. I have applied most recent HotFix 7.0.92 and on dev and staging sites, it looks fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I think, recycling the AppPool should solve the issue, and if the IIS is configured for `Overlapping` recycling, the users should notice that it is happening. Info from [IIS MS Docu](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770764%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

> ...
>   Overlapping recycling, the default, lets an unhealthy worker process
>   become marked for recycling, but continues handling requests that this
>   unhealthy process **has already received**. It does not accept new
>   requests from HTTP.sys. When all existing requests are handled, the
>   unhealthy worker process shuts down.
>   ...

I hope this helps.

Comment: Before posting my problem, i went through these steps. I shut down and then restarted the site as well. This Kentico site is setup as an application under our custom MVC solution. The same problem showed up for me on staging (2 servers) and production (2 servers) as well. This doesn't looks like an environment issue, but rather a project issue. We have another custom classic asp.net site for internal use, and on the same servers and that is not showing this issue.